# send button click unfortunately "project name" has stopped

Tags: java, php, android-studio

I have a button that sends the entered data to the database, After clicking on the button, an error appears unfortunately "project namе" has stopped, please, help!!!!

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="kz.shoot.photo.photoshoot">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <!--uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"        /-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RegisterActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
             android:name=".MainActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MainActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package kz.shoot.photo.photoshoot;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
        displayView(0);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new PhotoShootFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_home);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new HistoryFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_history);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new AboutFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_about);
                break;
            case 3:
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }}
```

Fragment_Photoshoot.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="kz.shoot.photo.photoshoot.PhotoShootFragment">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/label"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:text="Мені? ?алам!"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Жібергі?із келген жерді? суретін т?сірі?із!"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/label"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/captured_photo"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/imageDesc"
                    android:theme="@android:style/Widget.ImageWell"
                    android:scrollIndicators="right"
                    android:layerType="hardware"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="false"
                    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:minHeight="250dp"
                    android:maxHeight="300dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                <Button
                    android:text="Камера"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/cameraBtn"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/captured_photo"
                    android:onClick="takePicture"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/mess_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/mess_title"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:text="Хабарлама категориясын та?да?ыз"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/category_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/message"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:hint="@string/photo_description"
                        android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
                        android:maxLines="25"
                        android:elevation="0dp"
                        android:minHeight="82dp"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                <Button
                    android:text="Жіберу"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/captured_photo"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: copy logcat information to here

Comment: please write the whole text in English

Comment: I have a button that sends the entered data to the database, After clicking on the button, an error appears unfortunately "project namе" has stopped, please, help!!!!